# fix column width in table without fixed layout

Tags: html, html-table

I have a table without fixed layout, which means width of column depends on cell content. Now I need to fix width for one column. Say there is minimum width for this column even though all cells are empty.

Or I can extend width for certain column.

Plz advise if this is doable and how to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: I have to apologize for this post. I asked very bad question, did not explain my issue very clearly.

For regular html table, answers from Sarfraz and Ken both work for fixed column width.

In my td cell there are some div elements, cell's width still needs to depend on content. What I should do is set width for div element.

Sorry again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give that td a class:

```
td .special { width:200px; }
```

Comment: I think you mean **.special** ;) (notice the dot in front of special)

Answer (score 0):

> Plz advise if this is doable and how
>   to do it.

Just specify the `width` for that particular `td`:

```
<td width="200"></td>
```

This will make only that td's width fixed.

Comment: It works fine for plain table. But it doesn't work for mvc, which i need to render each cell separately in a loop.

At least it works for plain html table. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix both mat-cell and mat-head in mat-table

```
    .mat-cell:nth-child(1),
.mat-header-cell:nth-child(1),
{
flex: 0 0 5%;
}
```